# Cannot convert std::string to in initialization

Tags: c++

I am having an odd problem:

metadata.h:

```
class metadata
{
    public:
        metadata ( std::string filename );
        template <class T> T get ( std::string key ) { return m_data.get<T> ( key ); }
    private:
        boost::property_tree::ptree m_data;
};
```

metadata.cpp:

```
metadata::metadata ( std::string filename )
{
    try {
        boost::property_tree::read_info ( filename, m_data );
    } catch ( boost::property_tree::file_parser_error err ) {
        std::cerr << "[!] Unable to open "
                  << filename
                  << ": "
                  << err.message()
                  << "!"
                  << std::endl;
        throw except ( "Error opening metadata file." );
    }
}
```

asset.h:

```
template <class T> class assetManager {
    public:
        void load ( std::string filename );
        T get ( std::string filename );
        T operator[] ( std::string filename );
        void drop ( std::string filename ) { m_assets.erase ( filename ); }
        void clear() { m_assets.clear(); }
    private:
        std::map<std::string,T> m_assets;
};

template <class T> void assetManager<T>::load ( std::string filename )
{
    if ( m_assets [ filename ] == nullptr ) {
        m_assets.erase ( filename );
        m_assets.insert ( std::pair <std::string,T> ( filename, new T ( filename ) ) );
    }
}

template <class T> T assetManager<T>::get ( std::string filename )
{
    T ret = m_assets.at ( filename );
    return ret;
}
```

For some reason, this line here:

```
m_metadata.load ( boost::filesystem::current_path().string() + "/engine.conf" );
```

I am getting the following compiler error from g++:

src/core/../core/../asset/asset.h|22|error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘metadata*’ in initialization

At no point, as far as I can tell, have I programmed anything even slightly resembling a conversion of a string into my metdata pointer here. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `m_metadata`? And if it is `metadata`, why are you calling `load` on it when it has no such member?

Comment: m_metadata is an assetManager<metadata*>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `assetManager<T>::load` this subexpression

```
std::pair <std::string,T> ( filename, new T ( filename ) )
```

is obviously incorrect. `new T` will produce `T *`. Meanwhile your pair is declared with `T` as its second member. You cannot use `T *` to initialize `T`, unless you have a proper conversion constructor in `T`.

If `T` is `metadata`, then for this problem I'd actually expect an error message saying that it is impossible to convert `metadata *` to `std::string`, not the other way around. You will see the same error if you attempt this

```
metadata m(new metadata("test"));
```

Another issue is that you are creating a pair in which the first member has type `std::string`. However, in `std::map<std::string, T>::value_type` the first member of the pair is actually `const std::string`. The code will compile, but it will require a conversion from your `std::pair<std::string, T>` to map's `std::pair<const std::string, T>`. This might become performance issue. Which is why a much better idea would be to use `std::map<std::string, T>::value_type` as pair type, instead of trying to spell it out manually.

---

In the comments you stated that `m_metadata` is `assetManager<metadata*>`. In that case `T` is `metadata *`. That explains everything, including the error message. In that case the problem is even more simple and localized. This

```
new T ( filename )
```

alone is what causing the error. That means that `new T` produces a `metadata *` object and attempts to initialize it with `std::string`. Hence the error message. It is not possible to initialize `metadata *` with `std::string` because it is not possible to convert `std::string` to `metadata *`.

On top of that, such `new` expression will return a `metadata **` value, which is definitely not what you need.

Comment: I'm not clear why it would do any conversion either way between std::string and metadata or metadata*. They're different parts of the std::pair.

Comment: @Yaro Kasear: The problem I described has nothing to do with any parts of the pair. The problem is that the code expects `metadata` and you give it `metadata *`. The program will attempt to convert `metadata *` to `metadata` by using that single conversion constructor you provided in `metadata` class. And to use that constructor it will attempt to convert `metadata *` to `std::string`, since the only parameter in that constructor is of `std::string` type.

Comment: what version g++? I've been using 4.8.1 (when I can) and I've noticed a substantial improvement in the usefulness of the compiler error messages over older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I changed m_metadata to an assetManager then made a few changes thus:

```
template <class T> class assetManager {
    public:
        void load ( std::string filename );
        T get ( std::string filename );
        T operator[] ( std::string filename );
        void drop ( std::string filename ) { m_assets.erase ( filename ); }
        void clear() { m_assets.clear(); }
    private:
        std::map<std::string,T*> m_assets;
};

template <class T> void assetManager<T>::load ( std::string filename )
{
    if ( m_assets [ filename ] == nullptr ) {
        m_assets.erase ( filename );
        m_assets.insert ( std::pair <std::string,T*> ( filename, new T ( filename ) ) );
    }
}

template <class T> T assetManager<T>::get ( std::string filename )
{
    T ret = *m_assets.at ( filename );
    return ret;
}
```

It compiles and runs now. Though my problem is fixed it *is* still a mystery to me why the compiler thinks I was trying a std::string to metadata* conversion.

Comment: If `m_metadata` is actually `assetManager<metadata*>`, then it is no mystery at all. See the second part of my answer.